# what is means by struct node , linked list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I'm watching a tutorial video "implementing linked list in C++". In that tutorial, I don't understand this code:

```cpp
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
```

The `struct` is a datatype, and what is meant by `node`? Is it a datatype or it's just a name? Also, I understand the `int data;` and what is `node* next;`? I know it's a pointer, and I know `next` is a name, what is `node`? Is it a name or a data type?

Comment: Its just a name and you could name it anything you want.

Comment: Whatever video your watching should be supplemented (superseded, actually) by a solid language reference and/or [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Not being clear what a `struct` is, how they're declared, and/or how it is used is fundamental to C++. In short: rewind and find an earlier video, and definitely get a good reference.

Comment: If you watch the tutorial without a good understanding about what _pointers_ are, it'll be hard to understand. Watch a tutorial about pointers first.

Comment: @Thirumal 131 - _Is it a name or a data type?_ - It is a name **of** a data type, defined by the `struct node` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `struct` keyword is used as follows

```
struct some_name_to_identify_the_structure{
  data types
};
```

In your code, it is defined as follows

```
struct node{
int data;
node *next;
};
```

this can be written as follows too

```
struct some_random_name_123{
int data;
some_random_name_123 *next;
};
```

So, it's just a name and `node *next` is a pointer to the structure itself.

Comment: how should I call it  , I mean if I create a " char function() { //some code };" I  call it as a function  , if I create a class I know it is class and I tell others it is a class , how should I tell other people what's it ,, is it a function that I creating using struct datatype ?? what is a name of it ?+

Comment: @Thirumal131 struct is a custom data type, that can contain different types of data types. Consider a basket with groceries, you will have fruits, veggies, and other different stuff in it. In this case, the basket is a struct, and the groceries in it are data types. You cannot call struct like a function, instead, it is used to declare a variable. Just like you declare an integer as `int a`, you can declare a struct variable as `node a` for your case. I suggest you follow a good C programming book to understand more in depth. If you did understand it, consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: yeah! , Now I get it ,, so thanks for clear explanation . It so helpful if you recommend me a book  and by the way I'm listening C++ and I know some basic like statement , loops , class , array and pointer .

Answer (score 1):

In short, a struct is a container for related data and methods and allows access and modification to data inside the struct which can be referenced through the name it's provided with.

So **node** here is the name it has been provided with.

Answer (score 1):

### The struct is a datatype, and what is meant by node? Is it a datatype or it's just a name? Also, I understand the int data; and what is node* next;? I know it's a pointer, and I know next is a name, what is node? Is it a name or a data type?

Node is a both a user-defined datatype and a name for your struct.
node* next means a pointer variable named next that points to a memory address of type node (points to another node struct).

In terms of a linked list, you have have a struct that represents a node. This node has some data in it (in this case an integer variable) and it also has a pointer to the next or another node struct of the same type. It's like a wagon in a train of many wagons or a chain in a chainlink.